# Did I mess up a constructor/method in this?

Tags: java

I don't get what is wrong. Something defintely is. I am just a noob. The idea is I put in all these parameters and run it on the TestMyInteger class. I am getting a major error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyInteger
    at TestMyInteger.main(TestMyInteger.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyInteger

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code

```
   public class MyInteger {
     private int value;


   public MyInteger (int value) {
     this.value = value;
  } //myInteger

 public int getValue() {
    return value;
   }//getValue

   public boolean isEven() {
     return (value % 2 == 0);

   }//isEven(not static)

   public boolean isOdd() {
     return (value % 2 != 0);

   }//isOdd(not static)

  public boolean isPrime() {
     int i = 0;
          for(i = 2; i <= value / 2; i++){
              if(value % i != 0)
                return true;
         }
          return false;

   }//isPrime (not static)

   public static boolean isEven (int n) {
      return (n % 2 == 0);

   }//isEven(static)

   public static boolean isOdd(int n) {
     return (n % 2 != 0);

  }//isOdd(static)

   public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
     int i = 0;
        for(i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++){
            if(n % i != 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;

   }//isPrime(static)

    public static boolean isEven(MyInteger n) {
       return n.isEven();

    }// myInteger isEven

    public static boolean isPrime(MyInteger o) {
     int i = 0;
          for(i = 2; i <= o / 2; i++){
            if(o % i != 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;

   } //myInteger prime

   public static boolean isOdd(MyInteger o) {
     return (o % 2 != 0);
   }//MyInteger isOdd

  public boolean equals(int anotherNum) {
   if (n1 == n2)
     return true;
      return false;
   } //what value is this (equals)

    public boolean equals(MyInteger o) {
      if (n1 == n2)
       return true;
       return false;

   `enter code here` }//MyInteger equals

   }
```

All of this will be run on this TestMyInteger class

```
public class TestMyInteger {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   MyInteger n1 = new MyInteger(5);
   System.out.println("n1 is even? " + n1.isEven());
   System.out.println("n1 is prime? " + n1.isPrime());
   System.out.println("15 is prime? " + MyInteger.isPrime(15)); 
   System.out.println("15 is even? " + MyInteger.isEven(15));

   MyInteger n2 = new MyInteger(24);
   System.out.println("n2 is odd? " + n2.isOdd()); 
   System.out.println("45 is odd? " + MyInteger.isOdd(45)); 
   System.out.println("n1 is equal to n2? " + n1.equals(n2));
   System.out.println("n1 is equal to 5? " + n1.equals(5)); 
   System.out.println("n2 is even? " + MyInteger.isEven(n2)); 
   System.out.println("n2 is odd? " + MyInteger.isOdd(n2)); 
   System.out.println("n2 is prime? " + MyInteger.isPrime(n2)); 
 }
}//TestMyInteger
```

Comment: Constructors/methods and how to reference them, keep track of them throughout the code is what is killing me the most :P

Comment: Have you compiled `MyInteger`? I see a number of bugs in your `equals` methods.... what are `n1` and `n2` in either `equals` (for example)?

Comment: I have tried and I get errors like

MyInteger.java:72: error: bad operand types for binary operator '/'

I am really noob at this, but n1 and n2  are defined in my TestMyInteger class
MyInteger n1 = new MyInteger(5)
        for(i = 2; i <= o / 2; i++){
                          ^
  first type:  MyInteger
  second type: int

Comment: my n1 and n2 are set in the TestMyInteger class.
MyInteger n1 = new MyInteger(5)
 MyInteger n2 = new MyInteger(24);

or am i missing something?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyInteger
 at TestMyInteger.main(TestMyInteger.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyInteger


This is what I am confused about because thursday it ran fine. I opened it today to check something and just ran it to verify and I got that message.

Answer (score 0):

**Delegate**, don't re-implement the same methods over and over. In order to access the `value` from a `MyInteger` instance you need to use `instance.value`. Your `isPrime` logic appears to be inverted. Don't try and change the signature of `Object.equals(Object)`. If you plan to override `equals`, you should override `hashCode` and `toString` as well. Like,

```
public class MyInteger {
    private int value;

    public MyInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    } // myInteger

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }// getValue

    public boolean isEven() {
        return isEven(value);
    }// isEven(not static)

    public boolean isOdd() {
        return isOdd(value);
    }// isOdd(not static)

    public boolean isPrime() {
        return isPrime(value);
    }// isPrime (not static)

    public static boolean isEven(int n) {
        return (n % 2 == 0);
    }// isEven(static)

    public static boolean isOdd(int n) {
        return !isEven(n);
    }// isOdd(static)

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }// isPrime(static)

    public static boolean isEven(MyInteger n) {
        return isEven(n.value);
    }// myInteger isEven

    public static boolean isPrime(MyInteger o) {
        return isPrime(o.value);
    } // myInteger prime

    public static boolean isOdd(MyInteger o) {
        return isOdd(o.value);
    }// MyInteger isOdd

    public boolean equals(int anotherNum) {
        return value == anotherNum;
    } // what value is this (equals)

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof MyInteger) {
            return equals(((MyInteger) o).value);
        }
        return false;
    }// MyInteger equals

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.hashCode(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

Until you can compile `MyInteger`, you can't use `MyInteger`. The computer doesn't know how.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am really new at this. I am taking a computer science 2 class in which we use java. All my constructors and methods were given by my instructor. He basically gave us a shell to work out. Like we just had to fill in the spaces between. I am kind of bummed about it because I guess I wouldn't get much practice with methods/constructors because that is what gets me stumped.

Comment: Like we have not touched the @Override stuff in class yet or anything about hashcode.

Comment: but why would I still get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyInteger
 at TestMyInteger.main(TestMyInteger.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyInteger
?

Comment: How are you compiling? How are you running? Have you compiled?

Comment: Yes. When I compile I get the message
"No main methods, JavaFX Applications.... found in file"

Which is weird, it should be pulling from my TestMyInteger.java file. I also listed that at the bottom of the post.

I am using JGRASP also.

Comment: Okay, so the TestMyJava did run, and I got 85% of it,

it went haywire after .. 
n2 is odd? false
45 is odd? true

Comment: This came up after it 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: MyInteger.equals(LMyInteger;)Z
 at TestMyInteger.main(TestMyInteger.java:12)

Answer (score 0):

```
public final class MyInteger {

    private final int value;

    public MyInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isEven() {
        return isEven(value);
    }

    public boolean isOdd() {
        return isOdd(value);

    }

    public boolean isPrime() {
        return isPrime(value);
    }

    public static boolean isEven(int value) {
        return value % 2 == 0;
    }

    public static boolean isOdd(int value) {
        return !isEven(value);
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int value) {
        if (Math.abs(value) < 2)
            return false;

        for (int i = 2, max = (int)Math.sqrt(value); i <= max; i++)
            if (value % i == 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        return obj instanceof MyInteger && value == ((MyInteger)obj).value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```